# How to sign with gapi-script module (Google auth API) in React Extension Manifest version 3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

When signing in with a third party auth provider like Google receiving following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.pt_BR.l4Bv_WkVC6g.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOuH5S2uqmF6E8zOW7n3yiqiwhzNQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error).
    at createErrorInternal (index-30f3030e.js:476:1)
    at _createError (index-30f3030e.js:448:1)
    at el.onerror (index-30f3030e.js:7051:1)
```

Login.js:

```
signInWithPopup(auth, provider.google)
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

I faced Content Security Policy error.

manifest.json:

```
"content_security_policy": {
       "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-eval'          https://apis.google.com 'unsafe-inline';"
   }
```